# Clarification about Carmichael's Lambda Function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, carmichael-function

By definition [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function) $\lambda(n)$ is the the smallest positive integer $m$ such that
$$
x^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}
$$
for **all** $1\leq x\leq n$ such that $\gcd(x,n)=1$. Moreover it is simple to compute $\lambda(n)$ thanks to Carmichael's theorem.

Consider now this problem: find the smallest positive integer $m$ such that 
$$
13^m\equiv 1\pmod{2013}
$$
Because $\gcd(13,2013)=1$ we have that $m=\lambda(2013)=60$. But we also have $13^{30}\equiv 1\pmod{2013}$ and of course $30<60$. This seems to contradict the Carmichael's theorem.
How it could be possible?

Thanks

Comment: The theorem doesn't say the the exponent is minimal for each value of $x$ - only for all $x$ (hence the alternative name *universal* exponent)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you wrote, $\lambda(n)$ is the the smallest positive integer $m$ such that
$x^m\equiv1\pmod n$ for all $1\le x \le n$ such that $\operatorname{gcd}(x,n)=1$.  The important words you seem to be overlooking are "for all".

Indeed, $13^{30}\equiv1\pmod {2013}$, but that's only one value of $x$.  For $x=2$, for example, $2^{30}\equiv 1585\pmod {2013}$, so $\lambda(2013)$ can't be $30$.  However, $2^{60}\equiv 1\pmod {2013}$, and the same is true for every other $x$ coprime to $2013$.

Answer (score 2):

$\lambda(n)$ is the the smallest positive integer $m$ such that
$$
x^m\equiv 1\pmod{n}
$$
for all $1\leq x\leq n$ such that $\gcd(x,n)=1$.

Because $\lambda(2013)=60,$ we have $x^{60}\equiv 1\pmod{2013}$ for all $x$ relatively prime to $n$.

$x^{30}\equiv 1\pmod{2013}$ may hold for some but not all such $x$.

For example, $17^{30}\not\equiv 1 \pmod{2013}.$